# Substituting HTML/Javascript Sidebar Gadgets?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, sidebar, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am a web developer and have a Windows Sidebar Gadget written in HTML/Javascript. It's very popular (500 000+ downloads) and users are requesting solutions for Windows 8 since gadget support has been removed. Microsoft will also remove the sidebar functionality in Windows 7.

What platform/SDK options are there for substituting a sidebar gadget?

I get all kinds of results from Google but none seems like an obvious choice. Adobe Air seems like a whole new piece of technology that requires a lot of learning. Simplicity is key and it's the main reason why i am so attached to sidebar gadgets.

These are the requirements:

- Runs on Windows
- HTML, Javascript, AJAX based
- Support for no window decoration (no titlebar, minimize- or close button)
- Minimum platform/SDK wrappers
- Ability to read/write xml data to disk

Bonus would be if:

- It also runs on Linux and Mac
- SDK/Platform dependencies could be included in the app package

Super-duper bonus would be if:

- The SDK is supported on handheld devices such as iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XUL). Meet all you check list:

> - Runs on Windows
> - HTML, Javascript, AJAX based
> - Support for no window decoration (no titlebar, minimize- or close button)
> - Minimum platform/SDK wrappers
> - Ability to read/write xml data to disk
> - It also runs on Linux and Mac

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL) you can find what is it. I hope it helps buddy.

Comment: Thank you for responding. At a first look this seems similar to the --app command line parameter for Google Chrome. I found a project that uses XUL Runner at http://pencil.evolus.vn.

Comment: And that seems not bad. Are you looking for something else tim?

Comment: Technology relying on the installed choice of browser could be a bit inconvenient. I looked a bit more at Adobe Air and it might not be that much foreign technology as I thought. The Hello World demo is actually quite similar to what a gadget is. The difference is when wrapping it up.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumbled upon this thread and looking for a way to create HTML/javascript desktop applications. I'm just gonna list [AppJS](http://www.appjs.org) as another potential SDK. The framework to embed with your scripts is 50 MB.

http://appjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

[TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/) seems like another multiplatform option similar to AppJS.

http://www.tidesdk.org/